# difference between the prepositions "to" and "for" in context?

Tags: difference

Tell me please if there is any difference between the following sentences!

> **To** me that mistake was a disaster.
>
> **For** me that mistake was a disaster.

Does in the first sentence the speaker mean that the disaster has a huge affect on him, and in the second he mean that the mistake is a disaster in his opinion and that didn't experience any consequences?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to try inverting the sentences a little to help you answer this question.

> That mistake was a disaster for me.

This sentences implies that the  **mistakeed me personally, or caused me disaster.**

> That mistake was a disaster to me

This sentence has less of an implication that the mistake affected "me" directly, but rather that **the mistake was interpreted by me to be a disaster.**